# Fair way to split fees

Tags: word-problem, fair-division

So I have a very simple problem, but I am unable to find a proper solution top it.

Four friends rented and apartment for 1 year. They paid \$590 of deposit each (\$2360 total).

By the end of the year, they received \$1470 back from their landlord because there were some unexpected bills. They calculated that each one was responsible for 44%, 34%, 15% and 7% of that extra charge (imagine the difference is in extra energy consumption or damages for example).

If they were to divide the deposit in 4 equal parts, they each would get \$367,5 (\$1470/4), but that is not fair as one of them only overspent 7% .

What would be the fair value each one should receive?

(I'm sorry for the probably wrong tags, I didn't know which to pick)

Thanks

Comment: Did the four friends really trust the computed percentages? How did they work out the difference in energy consumption? Sounds more of a homework problem than a real situation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overage is $\$890$ ($2360-1470=890$).

Suppose I am responsible for $44\%$ of the overage.  That makes $0.44\times\$890=\$391.60.$  Then, I should get back $\$198.40$ (my $\$590$ deposit *less* the overage for which I am responsible).

Use this method to calculate the rest.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very interesting approach.